# storing lines in an array awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file "test"cat , below is the content of the file :

```
a,s,d,e,g,h,j,k,l
q,w,e,e,t,y,u,i,o,k,i
z,x,c,f,b,n,m,a,s,j
q,a,z,e,s,x,e,d,c,ty,yt
w,s,c,f,d,c,r,f,v,o,o,o,y,i
t,g,b,e,h,n,u,h,n
```

now with respect to $4 column, i have to keep line into array and then print the same at the last :

output should be like this :

```
e :: a,s,d,e,g,h,j,k,l
e :: q,w,e,e,t,y,u,i,o,k,i
e :: q,a,z,e,s,x,e,d,c,ty,yt
e :: t,g,b,e,h,n,u,h,n
f :: z,x,c,f,b,n,m,a,s,j
f :: w,s,c,f,d,c,r,f,v,o,o,o,y,i
```

I am doing it through awk with below command, but not getting proper output.

```
awk -F"," '{sessions[$4]++;event_arr[$4][sessions[$4]]=$0; } END{ for ( i in sessions) {for (j in event_arr[i]) print i,"::",event_arr[i][j]}}'  test

#output
e :: t,g,b,e,h,n,u,h,n
e :: a,s,d,e,g,h,j,k,l
e :: q,w,e,e,t,y,u,i,o,k,i
e :: q,a,z,e,s,x,e,d,c,ty,yt
f :: z,x,c,f,b,n,m,a,s,j
f :: w,s,c,f,d,c,r,f,v,o,o,o,y,i
```

The issue, I am getting with the command is I am not getting output in proper sequence.

Comment: If you don't care about the output format, you don't even need awk.  `sort -t, -k4,1 test` acts as you describe, sorting col 4 then col 1 and up (resulting in 1,4,2,6,5,3), but –like all of the answers so far– this does not match your requested output (1,2,4,6,3,5).

Answer (score 1):

Simple **awk** + **sort** approach:

```
awk -F, '{ print $4" :: "$0 }' test | sort -t,
```

The output:

```
e :: a,s,d,e,g,h,j,k,l
e :: q,a,z,e,s,x,e,d,c,ty,yt
e :: q,w,e,e,t,y,u,i,o,k,i
e :: t,g,b,e,h,n,u,h,n
f :: w,s,c,f,d,c,r,f,v,o,o,o,y,i
f :: z,x,c,f,b,n,m,a,s,j
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNU awk, you can control how associative arrays are traversed: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html#Controlling-Scanning

For instance, here, you want to scan through the array with the keys sorted numerically, so

```
 awk -F, '
      {
          sessions[$4]++
          event_arr[$4][sessions[$4]]=$0
      }
      END {
          PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc" 
          for ( i in sessions) 
              for (j in event_arr[i]) 
                  print i,"::",event_arr[i][j]
      }
  '  test
```

However, that might destroy the alphabetical ordering of column 4

The issue is that you need to mix associative arrays and numerically indexed arrays. I'd head to a language like perl where that is more explicit:

```
perl -F, -ane '
    push @{$event{$F[3]}}, "$F[3] :: $_"
  } END {
    for $key (sort keys %event) {print join("", @{$event{$key}})}
' test
```

`%event` is a hash (an associative array).
`$event{$key}` is an array (numerically indexed).
In perl parlance, this is a hash-of-arrays.